# Script for automating rsync between two machines (ssh, rsync, mysqldump involved)

Tags: ssh, bash, rsync, shell-scripting

I'm trying to create a bash script to automate a process that backups my WordPress blog (on a VPS) on my NAS. I always do it manually, but I'd like to just launch a command and let the thing do its work. What I do usually:

On the NAS

1. ssh user@NAS-IP
2. Enter password
3. cd backupblog /* the directory I sync the backups to */
4. rsync -avhP -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress user@VPS-IP:/blog/directory --exclude 'wp-content/cache' .
5. Enter password for the VPS-IP user

Then, on the VPS

1. ssh user@VPS-IP
2. Enter password
3. mysqldump -uDBuser -pDBpassword DBname > WP_blog-ddmmyyyy.sql
4. exit

Then again on the NAS

6. rsync -avhP -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress user@VPS-UP:/blog/directory/WP_blog-ddmmyyyy.sql .
7. exit

I've seen I can automate ssh connections [with expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928004/how-to-enter-ssh-password-using-bash) but I think that's not the way to continue automating things via the script. Can you help?

Comment: Conceptually: **1.** use **ssh keys** (without  passwords) for authentication to prevent getting asked for passwords. (For extra security and credit: Make use of the options section in ˜/.ssh/authorized_keys` files to impose limits on what is allowed with that passwordless key.) **2.** make use of the fact that you can remotely trigger a script/command over ssh with `ssh user@host command-or-script`

Comment: I can explore that, thank you.